# How to generate an identity column in hyperion interactive reporting?

Tags: reporting, hyperion

I want to display an auto-incremented series (basically the row number) in a new column. How do I go about doing this in Hyperion Interactive Reporting ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new computed column and assign it a value of 1.
Then, create another computed column which will have a cumulative sum of the previous computed column. The function to be used is Cume().